# Cannot get location with Geolocation API on PWA

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, geolocation, progressive-web-apps

I am reaching you because I am facing an issue regarding the gathering of GPS coordinates using only the GPS module of an android tablet device through a Progressive Web Application made with React in Javascript.

I need to collect the GPS coordinates of the tablet even when there is no internet connection. Permissions are granted. The code is working perfectly until Google Chrome V104. Starting at Chrome V105, coordinates are not gathered offline anymore. I am using the Javascript Geolocation API to get the coordinates.
Regarding the logs of the app, it looks like the callbacks of the Geolocation API are completely ignored and are not even called.

Do you know why the geolocation callbacks are completely ignored ?

Here is the functions where I do the Geolocation API calls:

**location.js:**

```
module.exports = class Location {

  constructor() {
    this.ready = 'geolocation' in navigator
    this.id = null
  }

  get() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (!this.ready) return reject(new Error('no geolocation in navigator'))

      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        (position) => {
          const coord = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude,
            alt: position.coords.altitude
          }
          return resolve(coord)
        },
        (error) => {
          return reject(error)
        }
      )
    })
  }

  watch(resolve, reject) {
    const options = {
      maximumAge: 5 * 60 * 1000 // 5 minutes is the maximum age of a possible cached position that is acceptable to return
    }

    this.id = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
      (position) => {
        const coord = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude,
          alt: position.coords.altitude
        }
        return resolve(coord)
      },
      (error) => {
        return reject(error)
      },
      options
    )
  }

  clean() {
    if (this.id === null) return
    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.id)
  }

}
```

**Call to the location functions from Shell.js (componentDidMount):**

```
async componentDidMount () {
    try {
      const position = await location.get()
      log.info(`location.get() returns ${JSON.stringify(position)}`)
    } catch (error) {
      log.error('location.get() errors', error)
    }

    location.watch(
      (position) => {
        // Decrease alt precision
        if (position.alt) position.alt = parseInt(position.alt)

        // A GPS fix has already been made
        if (this.state.position !== null) {
          function equalTo5(a, b) {
            return a.toFixed(5) === b.toFixed(5)
          }

          const sameLat = equalTo5(this.state.position.lat, position.lat)
          const sameLng = equalTo5(this.state.position.lng, position.lng)
          if (sameLat && sameLng) return

          server.setPosition(position)
          this.setState({position})
        } else {
          log.info(`GPS reading ${JSON.stringify(position)}`)
          server.setPosition(position)
          this.setState({position})
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        if (error.message.startsWith('Only secure origins are allowed')) {
          const position = {lat: 13, lng: 37, alt: 1337}
          log.info(`GPS fake reading ${JSON.stringify(position)}`)
          this.setState({position})
          return
        }

        log.error('GPS cannot get location', error)
        if (this.state.position === null) this.setState({positionError: error})
      })

    this.getServiceWorkerRegistration()
  }
```

I checked the documentation, the code didn't got deprecated, and the functions' signature are always the same.

I looked at the Google Chrome release notes but nothing is specified about a potential change about the way the position is acquiered, or the requirements for this feature to work.

I am doing a call to getCurrentPosition and then I am watching the changes of the position once I have one.

Regarding the Android settings, I disable everything that lead to use something else than the GPS feature to get the coordinates.

To give you a bit more of context, the tablet is connected to a wifi network emitted from a wifi chip embedded into a machine. The machine's wifi doesn't provide access to internet.

I tested the code over Android 8 and 11, and over Google Chrome V70 (Android 8 only), V90, V104, V105, V106, V107, V108

Thanks for your help